# Insightly CRM Ajax API proxy

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, cors, crm

**UPDATE**

Hi I am currently having getting an error with CORS when trying to connect to Insightlys CRM's API. I am successfully retrieving my Insightly CRM data through POSTMAN.

Insightly does not support CORS for AJAX requests (http://support.insight.ly/hc/en-us/community/posts/206961417-Using-the-API-with-AJAX) and you have to setup an API proxy script. I have used the below supplied proxy script done in python and uploaded to my dedicated hosting. But I am still getting a 401 error?

I am quite new to API proxies so not sure if I am missing something here?

```
GET https://api.insight.ly/v2.2/Contacts 401 (Unauthorized)
```

apiproxy.py

```
#
# Insightly API Proxy for Python / App Engine
# Brian McConnell <brian@insightly.com>
#
# This utility is designed to act as an API proxy server. It is written in  Python 2.7
# and will run without modification on Google App Engine. Just serve your JavaScript
# from the /js directory in this project, and AJAX requests should be relayed through
# to the Insightly service. This should also run on any webapp2 compatible server platform
#

import base64
import os
import string
import types
import urllib
import urllib2
import webapp2
import wsgiref.handlers

#
# import google app engine libraries, replace these with standard 
#

try:
    from google.appengine.ext import webapp
except:
# skip Google App Engine webapp library
    pass

base_url = 'https://api.insight.ly/v2.2'

def authenticate():
#
# add user validation logic here, be careful to do this in a way that does not expose user secrets such as
# the user API key (this is why we do not allow CORS in the first place)
#

# hardcoding API key for now

apikey = 'fillinhere'
return base64.encode(apikey)

def generateRequest(url, method, data, alt_auth=None, test=False, headers=None):
"""
This method is used by other helper functions to generate HTTPS requests and parse server responses. This will minimize the amount of work developers need to do to integrate with the Insightly API, and will also eliminate common sources of errors such as authentication issues and malformed requests. Uses the urllib2 standard library, so it is not dependent on third party libraries like Requests
"""
if type(url) is not str: raise Exception('url must be a string')
if type(method) is not str: raise Exception('method must be a string')
valid_method = False
response = None
text = ''
if method == 'GET' or method == 'PUT' or method == 'DELETE' or method == 'POST':
valid_method = True
else:
raise Exception('parameter method must be GET|DELETE|PUT|UPDATE')
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.get_method = lambda: method
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
if headers is not None:
headerkeys = headers.keys()
for h in headerkeys:
    request.add_header(h, headers[h])
# open the URL, if an error code is returned it should raise an exception
if method == 'PUT' or method == 'POST':
result = urllib2.urlopen(request, data)
else:
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
text = result.read()
return text

class APIProxyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def delete(self):
    apikey = authenticate()
    path_qs = self.request.headers['path_qs']
    url = base_url + path_qs
    headers = {'Authorization','Basic ' + api_key}
    text = generateRequest(url, 'DELETE', None, headers=headers)
    self.response.headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
    self.response.out.write(text)
def get(self):
    apikey = authenticate()
    path_qs = self.request.headers['path_qs']
    url = base_url + path_qs
    headers = {'Authorization','Basic ' + api_key}
    text = generateRequest(url, 'GET', None, headers=headers)
    self.response.headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
    self.response.out.write(text)
def post(self):
    body = self.request.headers['body']
    path_qs = self.request.headers['path_qs']
    url = base_url + path_qs
    headers = {'Authorization','Basic ' + api_key}
    text = generateRequest(url, 'POST', body, headers=headers)
    self.response.headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
    self.response.out.write(text)
def put(self):
    body = self.request.headers['body']
    path_qs = self.request.headers['path_qs']
    url = base_url + path_qs
    headers = {'Authorization','Basic ' + api_key}
    text = generateRequest(url, 'PUT', body, headers=headers)
    self.response.headers['Content-Type']='application/json'
    self.response.out.write(text)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([("r/(.*)", APIProxyHandler)], debug=True)
# map generic page server request handler
```

jQuery/Ajax call:

```
Insightly = function () {
var _t = this;

this.events = function () {
    $(".contactsform").submit(_t.searchContacts);
};
this.searchContacts = function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var $search = $(this);
console.log('[ Search contacts event ]');

$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options ) {
    if ( options.crossDomain ) {
    var newData = {};

    newData.data = $.extend({}, options.data);
    newData.url = options.url;

    options = {};

    // Set the proxy URL
    options.url = "http://www.blahblah.comm/apiproxy.py";
    console.log("ajaxprefilter");
    options.data = $.param(newData);
    console.log(options);
    options.crossDomain = false;
}
});
// How to use the cross domain proxy
$.ajax({         
    url: 'https://api.insight.ly/v2.2/Contacts',
    crossDomain: true, 
    processData: false 
    }).success(function(data) { 
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data); 
    console.log(jsonData); 
});
};//End SearchContacts
this.init = function () {
    _t.events();
};
this.init();
return (this);   
};//End main function
var LZ = new Insightly();
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does their content type support JSONP (Json with Padding)?  You need to treat the response as javascript. This usually solves the CORS problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I wasn't able to find anything in their docs ref jsonp. However I did try setting the dataType to jsonp and got a GET 401 error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you cannot access their API directly using AJAX or javascript http request from the client-side. What you need to do is create a "Proxy" API.

A "Proxy" API is the service that you need to host in your own domain where the client code lies. You need to write an authenticated server-side API call to Insightly CRM API with your favorite server-side language and call this with your jquery AJAX.

So the following code will be:

```
var searchNotesUrl = "https://myowndomain.com/your/api/proxy/notes"
```

In other words, your server-side script will be the one relaying the data from CRM API to your client.

If it is still getting 401 response, then maybe you need to check the User and API Key credentials if they are correct.

**UPDATE**

You entirely changed the question now. My answer above was intended for the last question version that you had.

For new answer, you have a problem with this code:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options ) {
    if ( options.crossDomain ) {
    var newData = {};

    newData.data = $.extend({}, options.data);
    newData.url = options.url;

    options = {};

    // Set the proxy URL
    options.url = "http://www.blahblah.comm/apiproxy.py";
    console.log("ajaxprefilter");
    options.data = $.param(newData);
    console.log(options);
    options.crossDomain = false;
}
});
// How to use the cross domain proxy
$.ajax({         
    url: 'https://api.insight.ly/v2.2/Contacts',
    crossDomain: true, 
    processData: false 
    }).success(function(data) { 
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data); 
    console.log(jsonData); 
});
```

First, you are still requesting to the `'https://api.insight.ly/v2.2/Contacts'` . You do not need to request to this URL anymore as you already have the proxy api. The proxy api (`"http://www.blahblah.comm/apiproxy.py"`) is the one that you should be directly calling instead of sending request to insight.ly.

Your Proxy API, should handle all api request that can be sent in insight.ly. Which means that `"http://www.blahblah.comm/apiproxy.py"` can support `notes` , `Contacts` and etc.

Second, as you can read the python script, it actually looks for a request header key `'path_qs'` . The `path_qs` value should be something like `/Contacts`. The reason being is because `path_qs` is being concatenated with `base_url = 'https://api.insight.ly/v2.2'` inside the script thru `url = base_url + path_qs`.

So the code would be like:

```
$.ajax({ 
   method: 'GET', //this is because it is supposed to be GET
   crossDomain: true,
   dataType: 'json',
   url: 'http://www.blahblah.comm/apiproxy/that/executes', 
   headers: { 'path_qs': '/Contacts' },
   success : function(data, status, xhr) {
      console.log(data);
   }
});
```

You need to setup the Python script in Google app engine cloud as an application. To learn more, this is entirely new topic: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. The Insightly tech guy said the same thing and provided me with a python proxy script which only works on Google App Engine and has webapp2, but I'd like to use it on my existing dedicated host (because of cost) so will need modifications. I am new to API proxy scripts, I believe you can do this in with Nodejs/expressjs as well? Script needs to capture the Accept, Content-Type and Authorization heads

Comment: @RRowan Yes , nodejs/express can do the proxy script using the http module. I've found some snippets / tutorial for you : https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request

Comment: Hi Vincent, thanks for your help. I have attempted to use a python script  https://github.com/Insightly/insightly-python/blob/v2.2/apiproxy.py that the tech support supplied and updated my code/post above but still getting a 401 message. I believe the credentials are correct. Webhost says they support webapp2 and python as well.

Comment: @RRowan is your client code hosted in the same server as your py script? If you are using chrome, actually you can test your python service first using POSTMAN (a chrome extension) to verify that your code is working then you can integrate it in your javascript. It can test your HTTP responses. This is good practice to test it there first to isolate the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I successfully retrieved data /information from POSTMAN in the first instance connecting to the insightly API directly with api key/basic auth. But do you mean connecting/testing to the apiproxy.py script through postman? If so what would be the best way to test? I am working locally and have my apiproxy.py on server

Comment: Hi Vincent thanks for your help. Sorry about changing my question, wasn't sure if I should of asked a new question.Thanks your code works - but only when I removed 'dataType: json' as there was a 'parseerror'. But the success console.log message showed the contents of the apiproxy file, instead of the /Contacts json data which is what I am after.

Comment: Meaning you are serving the python script as a content file and not an executable.  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction

Comment: Thanks heaps Vincent. My webhost came back and said they need to setup a python virtual environment and webapp2 framework after they initially said they can support it. Going through the python appengine docs you sent. Cheers

Comment: Hi Vincent. I have posted another question following on from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990374/python-google-app-engine-api-proxy. Your assitance would be great! Cheers